# why browser crashes when push() is run within a for loop like below

Tags: javascript, for-loop, push

I was trying to multiply each of the values in an array by 2 and push the value to another array at each loop. I have no idea why the following code seems to triger an infinite loop which crashes the browser. I have other solutions to get the same result but I just wanted to know the root cause behind the crash so please educate me. Thanks!

```
multipliedBy([1,2,3], 2) //expected result: [1,2,3,2,4,6]

function multipliedBy(arr, num){
   var oldArr = arr;
   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      oldArr.push(arr[i] * num);
   }
   return oldArr;
}
```

Comment: Because `oldArr` and `arr` point on the same array, hence `arr.length` changes with every `.push()`

Comment: I know it's not what you asked, but I'd do this as a one liner: `return arr.concat(arr.map(elt => elt * num));`

Comment: Thanks all! those are good answers. and @Robin yeah I ended up using map()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this way with **cloning** the array instead of referring the **same** array while using `push()`,

```js
console.log(multipliedBy([1,2,3], 2)) //expected result: [1,2,3,2,4,6]

function multipliedBy(arr, num){
   var oldArr = [...arr]; //clone using spread 
   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      oldArr.push(arr[i] * num);
   }
   return oldArr;
}
```

**Useful note from comment:** Because `oldArr` and `arr` point on the same array, hence `arr.length` changes with every `.push()` - **Andreas**

Answer (score 0):

When you do `var oldArr = arr;` it is a reference to `arr`. In the loop you are looking at the length `arr.length` and when you push to oldArr, you are pushing to arr and the length keeps increasing so you keep looping.

```js
function multipliedBy(arr, num) {
  var oldArr = arr.slice(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    oldArr.push(arr[i] * num);
  }
  return oldArr;
}

console.log(multipliedBy([1, 2, 3], 2))
```

or if you do not want to clone the array, than just set it a variable before you alter it.

```
var oldArr = arr;
var len = arr.length;
for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
```